# How to clarify this question answered with two different interpretations?

Tags: discussion, editing

I read the following question: [Probability of selecting 2 points on a straight line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163612/probability-of-selecting-2-points-on-a-straight-line).
I read the different answers and got confused at first because two peoples answered to different interpretations of the problem but don't give their interpretation in the answer ; and the third answer gives graphics to illustrate the two answers but does not neither explain explicitly what are the interpretation.

I enter in the details of the question now. I am pretty sure that the question is about the distance $AB$ and not a product of numbers $A$ and $B$ because the OP does not say something like "we take $A$ and $B$ in the interval $[0,10]$".
A simple edit of the question replacing $AB>4$ by $AB>4\text{cm}$ would avoid this confusion when reading the question but it would still be confusing because of the different answers.

Also I would suggest the tittle to be edited to "Probability that the distance between two random points is greater than $4$" or "Distance between random points in a segment".

Comment: Note also that I think it is worth to clarify the question (and add the tag [geometric-probability]) because this actually one of the most basic and classical problem of geometric probability.

Comment: The question is 2 years old. I don't think that such old questions need to be revisited to clarify them, particularly since the OP has not been active. It should be up to the OP to edit their own question, but in this case they even accepted an answer.